# Prevent Ajax.BeginForm from HTML encoding output

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Comment", 
    new AjaxOptions
    { 
        UpdateTargetId = "newComment",
        OnSuccess = "function() { alert('finished " + ViewData.Model.Id + "'); }",
    }))
{
   ...
}
```

outputs the following markup:

```
<form action="/Comment/Create" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" 
 data-ajax-success="function() { alert(&#39;finished 34&#39;); }" 
 data-ajax-update="#newComment34" id="form1" method="post">
```

As you can see, it has HTML encoded my javascript.  How do I prevent this?

**EDIT**: I have multiple AJAX forms on my page so the onsuccess function needs to know which one called it.  In my code, you can see I am trying to pass state to this function.  If OnSuccess can only take a function name (and not state), then how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would use a standard `Html.BeginForm` helper with HTML5 `data-*` attributes that I will AJAXify myself:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
    "Create", 
    "Comment", 
    FormMethod.Post, 
    new { data_id = Model.Id }
))
{
    ...
}
```

which outputs:

```
<form action="/Comment/Create" data-id="some id here" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

and then in a separate javascript file I would subscribe for the `.submit` event:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataId: $(this).data('id'), // <- pass the data-id HTML5 attribute
            success: handleSuccess
        });
        return false;
    });
});

function handleSuccess(result) {
    $('#newComment').html(result);

    // fetch the data-id of the form that trigerred the AJAX request
    var id = this.dataId; 

    // TODO: do something with this id
}
```

I prefer this technique compared to the `Ajax.*` helpers as it gives me all the control I might need. Another advantage is that we get a clear separation between script and markup making the code nice and tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

The HTML encoding is correct behavior, and the attribute value (as seen from Javascript code) will not be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that It's because MVC interprets the OnSuccess (and other vars) as the name of a Javascript function and not a bit of Script.

Make a helper function that performs the script you want to act on the submit.

Comment: Then how do I pass state to this function? There are multiple such ajax forms on my page, and the success function needs to know which one called it.